# Need help - Multiple attachment in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

How to change this script to attach 5 attachment and to send email :
Pls help in  changing the script accordingly to accept more attachment and to send email

```html
###########Define Variables######## 

$fromaddress = "donotreply@labtest.com" 
$toaddress = "Aishwarya.Rawat@labtest.com" 
$bccaddress = "Vikas.sukhija@labtest.com" 
$CCaddress = "Mahesh.Sharma@labtest.com" 
$Subject = "ACtion Required" 
$body = get-content .\content.htm 
$attachment = "C:\sendemail\test.txt" 
$smtpserver = "smtp.labtest.com" 

#################################### 

$message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$message.From = $fromaddress 
$message.To.Add($toaddress) 
$message.CC.Add($CCaddress) 
$message.Bcc.Add($bccaddress) 
$message.IsBodyHtml = $True 
$message.Subject = $Subject 
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment) 
$message.Attachments.Add($attach) 
$message.body = $body 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver) 
$smtp.Send($message)
```

Comment: are you limited to use only powershell v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to your main question about modifying the code to attach multiple file**

assuming that all your attachments exist under `C:\sendemail\`

we will modify the variable `attachment` to include all the files under `C:\sendemail\` as follow

```
$attachment = (Get-ChildItem C:\sendemail\ -File).FullName

# or if you would like $attachment = @("C:\sendemail\file1.txt","C:\sendemail\file2.txt","C:\sendemail\file3.txt")
```

and then we will loop through the files of `attachement` to create `Net.Mail.Attachment` object and add it to the `message` like that:

```
foreach ($att in $attachment){
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($att)
$message.Attachments.Add($attach)
}
```

so your final code will be something like that:

```
###########Define Variables######## 

$fromaddress = "donotreply@labtest.com" 
$toaddress = "Aishwarya.Rawat@labtest.com" 
$bccaddress = "Vikas.sukhija@labtest.com" 
$CCaddress = "Mahesh.Sharma@labtest.com" 
$Subject = "ACtion Required" 
$body = get-content .\content.htm 
$attachment = (Get-ChildItem C:\sendemail\ -File).FullName
$smtpserver = "smtp.labtest.com" 

#################################### 

$message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$message.From = $fromaddress 
$message.To.Add($toaddress) 
$message.CC.Add($CCaddress) 
$message.Bcc.Add($bccaddress) 
$message.IsBodyHtml = $True 
$message.Subject = $Subject 
foreach ($att in $attachment){
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($att)
$message.Attachments.Add($attach)
}
$message.body = $body 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver) 
$smtp.Send($message)
```

**If you are not limited to Powershell V1, you could use the `Send-MailMessage` command**

```
 Send-MailMessage -From $fromaddress -to $toaddress -Cc $CCaddress -Bcc $bccaddress -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Body $body -Subject $Subject
```